# how can I spend those weeks in MySQL in this table?

Tags: mysql

So I want to release the weeks in MySQL here in this table but how do I do that I had tried something but nothing can be released here can anyone here help me and give a good example if it is possible. year weeks must be included.

a little explanation here if I have to calculate a score every week I have to see that. and if I do that every week I always see a zero here a picture
I hope you understand a little what I mean

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NowXF.png)

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.4.14
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Dec 12, 2017 at 10:59 AM
-- Server version: 5.6.26
-- PHP Version: 5.5.28

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `stefaanphp`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tblusers`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblusers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Auditeur` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `Afdeling` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `Zone` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `Stand` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `Score` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `number1` char(11) NOT NULL,
  `number2` char(11) NOT NULL,
  `number3` char(11) NOT NULL,
  `number4` char(11) NOT NULL,
  `number5` char(11) NOT NULL,
  `number6` char(11) NOT NULL,
  `number7` char(11) NOT NULL,
  `PostingDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Week` INTEGER NOT NULL -- 1 to 52/53
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tblusers`
--

INSERT INTO `tblusers` (`id`, `Auditeur`, `Afdeling`, `Zone`, `Stand`, `Score`, `number1`, `number2`, `number3`, `number4`, `number5`, `number6`, `number7`, `Week`,`PostingDate`) VALUES
(1, 'stef', 'Combine', 'Hoofdlijn st1-4 + Onderraam 1010', 'St 6008', 'Totale Score:10', '5', '3', '3', '5', '10', '5', '1', '02', '2019-02-12 08:27:53');


--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `tblusers`
--
ALTER TABLE `tblusers`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `tblusers`
--
ALTER TABLE `tblusers`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=7;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

and I still have a question to change that date with time to only date can not get time I had already done many other options for example date just get 000-00-0000

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: can you rephrase your question? its a little unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Very unclear. What do you want to do with the weeks?

Comment: is there a reason for storing incrementing number columns they should be ideally be normalized to a other table.  Using incrementing number columns is considerd bad practice in SQL.

Comment: when I push through my form on submit button to save in the database, I see nothing but a 0.

Comment: year weeks must be included.

Comment: I've really no idea what your problem is, but will observe that any time you find yourselves with enumerated columns, seriously consider whether your schema deisgn is optimal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your week question: you can use the MySQL week function to calculate the weeknumber of specific dates:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week
The function expects a date or datetime, so you can just use the PostingDate that you are using in your insert statement.

About the other questions: maybe rephrase it so we can understand what you actually are asking.